# Named scope SQL syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, named-scope, named

Looks like I have some problems with quotes?

My named scope:

```
named_scope :find_by_name, lambda {|name| {:conditions => ["first_name LIKE '%?%' or last_name LIKE '%?%'",  name.split(' ').first, name.split(' ').last]}}
```

And here's how I'm doing a search:

```
find_by_name("#{search}")
```

And here's the generated SQL and error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'foo'%' or last_name LIKE '%'foo'%')' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE (first_name LIKE '%'foo'%' or last_name LIKE '%'foo'%')):
```

Comment: Please try last_name LIKE '%'+ ? +'%' and first_name like '%'+ ? +'%' in your named scope and let me know if works

Comment: Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+'aen'+'%' or last_name LIKE '%'+'tan'+'%')' at line 1: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (first_name LIKE '%'+'aen'+'%' or last_name LIKE '%'+'tan'+'%')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to get rid of '%?%' in your SQL syntax and instead use this:

```
named_scope :find_by_name, lambda {|name| {:conditions => ["first_name LIKE ? or last_name LIKE ?",  '%' + name.split(' ').first + '%', '%' + name.split(' ').last + '%']}}
```

Please let me know if it works.
P.S. Also it is not good idea to define find_by_*something* scope, Rails alredy did it for you, ActiveRecord dynamicly defines such methods.

Comment: I'm a beginner. Are you saying that I should name it something else or is there a beter way to do it? name is a virtual attribute by the way.

Comment: If the **name** is virtual attribute so it is ok. Just remember that defining you own find_by_something can override existing rails method